# Run a VBScript using Start-Process

Tags: powershell, vbscript

I am trying to run a VBScript using some code I already have written for generically running executables. I have used it successfully with EXE & BAT files, but VBS files are giving me headaches.

I found [this](http://blogs.lostincreativity.com/sqldba/how-to-execute-vbscript-through-a-powershell-script/) that does it with CMD and `Invoke-Expression`, and [this](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Run-legacy-VBScripts-from-5c5e40da) that does it with `&`. But I have found no references to doing it with `Start-Process`, and when I try something simple like

```
Start-Process wscript.exe -ArgumentList:"UNC PATH TO HelperTest.vbs"
```

I get

> Execution of the Windows Script Host failed. (Not enough storage is
>   available to complete ths operation. )

But I can run the super simple VBS file directly no problem. This only happens when the VBS is on a network share. Running it locally works fine. Also, not including a fully qualified path works fine, as in

```
Start-Process wscript.exe -ArgumentList:"HelperTest.vbs"
```

So it's not an actual permissions issue on the share. Am I just bumping in to some obscure bug and I am not going to get this to work, or am I doing something wrong and getting confused by a not very helpful error message?

Comment: I have no explanation for your symptom, but note that `wscript.exe` is inherently asynchronous, so there is no need for `Start-Process`, so `wscript.exe "UNC PATH TO HelperTest.vbs"` should do. If you try that, do you still get an error?

Comment: @mklement0, the problem is I already have code in place that uses Start-Process, based on information provided in XML files. So I am trying to find a way to make it work with Start-Process so I don't need to do a code update, I just need to provide the correct info in the XML file. I am refactoring for PS5 now, and I can improve the code then, but I have a more short term need that limits me to using Start-Process.

Comment: I see. Regarding the error message: I found https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/106167/error-message-not-enough-server-storage-is-available-to-process-this-c, but if that were the problem, I presume that invocation without path would also fail. Or is the with-path invocation happening in a different user context?

Comment: I did try pushing that value to 0xC, with no impact. Pretty sure this is just Microsoft getting the error message totally wrong. Worst case scenario, the REAL reason I am trying to use a VBS file is to get around the (!@%#$#) fact that Microsoft doesn't provide a good way to make PowerShell run hidden, and I need this hacky VBS based workaround to get something to run at user logon and not look amateurish. For this short term need (fixing a corrupt icon cache, because Windows is an unstable hack :-) ) I may just accept that the user is going to see some 1990's Windows for a moment.

Comment: I see, but you're running _from_ PowerShell, so doesn't that mean that either you've already managed to hide the PowerShell console window or it is visible anyway?

Comment: It gets... complicated. :) I have a hacky VBS that ONLY runs my main user context PS1 with no arguments. That loads the XML and then does the Start-Process tasks based on the contents of the XML. To fix the icons problem I have written another PS1 to do the work, and a new VBS to generically run PS1 files with passed through arguments. But to make that work it seems I will either need to copy at least the VBS to the local TEMP and run it from there, then delete it after use, or accept the DOS ugliness. Neither is the end of the world, but I was hoping for some wscript argument in the XML.

Comment: And, the initial VBS based PS1 launcher is triggered via the Run key in the registry, so it isn't limited by Start-Process, and lives on the network happily.

Comment: That  is indeed complicated :) Final thoughts: is the problem related to running at user logon? You mention that running with a relative path works, but does running with a full path interactively, after logon work too? Either way, I suggest mentioning the fact that this is run via the Run key in the registry directly in your question.

Comment: At the moment I am just testing with a little stub PS1 to launch the new VBS file, I haven't gotten to testing the full stack yet. So the initial question is at least a simplified version of the issue, and it doesn't work there. One step at a time. :)

Comment: If you're running this at user logon, why run it from PowerShell in the first place? VBScripts can be run as logon scripts.

Comment: You could simply add `Powershell.exe -File C:\path\script.ps1` to the login script if you want it to be run via logon script.

Comment: Thanks for the Logon script ideas, but in this case that also is not an option. The reasons why are also complicated, mostly due to internal office politics. The key is, I have a tool in place, it runs at user logon already, it uses Start-Process exclusively, and whatever I come up with has to work in that scenario. If I CAN make it look nice I will, but if I can't; well, it's Windows, everyone is used to it looking a bit ugly at times. :)

Comment: This seems to work for me: `Start-Process -FilePath 'C:\Windows\system32\wscript.exe' -ArgumentList 'HelperTest.vbs' -WorkingDirectory 'Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::\\server\share\path'`  In this example, I fully-qualify the path to wscript.exe and inform Start-Process that the WorkingDirectory is the UNC share\path.  wscript.exe should be launched in that WorkingDirectory context.  Hope this helps.